# Python sunlight openstates api

Tags: python, api

```
import requests

def call():
payload = {'apikey':'myapikey', 'zip':'74120'}
bas_url = 'http://openstates.org/api/v1//legislators'
r = requests.get(bas_url, params = payload)
grab = r.json() 
return grab
```

so i want to call the sunlightfoundation.org api for `openstates/legislator/locate` (***possiblylocate?***)

but im returning a large amount of errors, if anyone could see whats wrong with this from top of their head i dont wanna clog the thread with the whole error message, but if someone really needs it ill comment it.

Comment: Hi Bradley, there isn't a lot of information here. For starters, a link to the API docs would save us time having to go and find them. Additionally, you don't necessarily need to provide the entire error message, if you can identify parts that you think are relevant such as the HTTP response code (ie. 400, 404 etc). Alternatively, if you can't decide which parts are relevant, it would be much easier to help if you provided the whole error message.

Comment: thanks for helping me so much to help you.
http://sunlightlabs.github.io/openstates-api/

Comment: Thanks Bradley. Immediately I can see there is a Python specific package available which you can install via `pip`. It'll be much easier to work with that so I suggest you look into it here: http://python-sunlight.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: ugh-_- i got it working once and got it to return the results of the entire state, so i edited 'openstates' and added locate as mentioned above to locate by zip. and started returning errors, now im back to not being able to retrieve anything, ill post more errors if your interested in helping still